# Get hours in range of start and end times in a pandas dataframe and group them by value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has these two columns: 'start_time' and 'end_time'

| start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 14:00:00 |
| 13:00:00 | 20:00:00 |
| 12:00:00 | 15:00:00 |
| 13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |
| 11:00:00 | 15:00:00 |
| 09:00:00 | 14:00:00 |

I want to get the times between each row as if they were appointments. For example, the first row has the times: 10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00 and 13:00:00 (No appointment at 14:00:00 because that's the 'end' time).

Lastly, I want to group these times by value. The final dataframe should look like this:

| time | count |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 5 |
| 11:00:00 | 4 |
| 12:00:00 | 7 |
| 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 14:00:00 | 6 |

What I mean by count is each time a value is in the range of the row (i.e. In the first 2 rows, the value '13:00:00' appears 2 times).

Thank you!

Comment: How did U get the count of 5 for 10:00:00? Also kindly add what you tried

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

This gives for each time a count of how often it occurs in one of the intervals (assuming each start and end time to be at a full hour and each interval only spanning within a single day):

```
import pandas as pd

s="""10:00:00   14:00:00
13:00:00    20:00:00
12:00:00    15:00:00
13:00:00    19:00:00
11:00:00    15:00:00
09:00:00    14:00:00"""
columns = ["start_time", "end_time"]
df = pd.DataFrame([r.split('\t') for r in s.split('\n')], columns=columns)

to_h = lambda x: int(x[:2])
hours = []
for s, e in zip(df.start_time.apply(to_h), df.end_time.apply(to_h)):
    hours.extend(list(range(s, e)))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(hours).value_counts())
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'index': 'time', 0: 'count'}, inplace=True)
from_h = lambda x: ('' if len(str(x)) == 2 else '0') + str(x) + ':00:00'
df2['time'] = df2['time'].apply(from_h)
print(df2)
```

prints

```
        time  count
0   13:00:00      6
1   12:00:00      4
2   14:00:00      4
3   11:00:00      3
4   10:00:00      2
5   15:00:00      2
6   16:00:00      2
7   17:00:00      2
8   18:00:00      2
9   19:00:00      1
10  09:00:00      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this, using `date_range` to find all the appointment times for each `start_time/end_time` pair, then `exploding` the resultant ranges and counting all the different times, before converting the resultant series into a dataframe:

```py
res = (df
    .sort_values('start_time')
    .apply(lambda r:pd.date_range(r['start_time'], r['end_time'], freq='1H', inclusive='left').time, axis=1)
    .explode()
    .value_counts(sort=False)
    .to_frame('count')
    .reset_index(names='time')
)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
        time  count
0   09:00:00      1
1   10:00:00      2
2   11:00:00      3
3   12:00:00      4
4   13:00:00      6
5   14:00:00      4
6   15:00:00      2
7   16:00:00      2
8   17:00:00      2
9   18:00:00      2
10  19:00:00      1
```